# In python, sorting on date field, field may sometimes be null

Tags: python, sorting

I am having a hard time coming up with a slick way to handle this sort.  I have data coming back from a database read.  I want to sort on the accoutingdate.  However, accoutingdate may sometimes be null.  I am currently doing the following:

```
results = sorted(results, key=operator.itemgetter('accountingdate'), reverse=True)
```

But, this bombs with "TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to NoneType" due to some accoutingdates being null.

What is the "most correct" or "most Pythonic" way to handle this?

Comment: Where does `None` fall in your sort?  First?  Last?  Somewhere in the middle?  What does `None` mean when compared with a Date?  Is `None` before or after December 7th 2001?

Comment: My preference would be to sort None as "before" all valid dates.

Comment: Btw, you can sort your list in place: `results = sorted(results, ... )` should simply be `results.sort( ... )`

Comment: "preference"?  It often helps to be more assertive in stating your requirements.  "It must come before all other dates", for example.

Comment: Understood. I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using a `key=` function is definitely right, you just have to decide how you want to treat the `None` values -- pick a `datetime` value that you want to treat as the equivalent of `None` for sorting purposes.  E.g.:

```
import datetime
mindate = datetime.date(datetime.MINYEAR, 1, 1)

def getaccountingdate(x):
  return x['accountingdate'] or mindate

results = sorted(results, key=getaccountingdate, reverse=True)
```

Just see how much simpler this is than defining a `cmp` function instead -- and if you do some benchmarking you'll find it's also significantly faster!  There's no upside at all in using  a `cmp` function instead of this `key` function, and it would be a bad design choice to do so.

Comment: I switched my accepted answer to this one... very slick!  Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `datetime.min`

Answer (score 13):

You could use a custom sorting function that treats `None` specially:

```
def nonecmp(a, b):
  if a is None and b is None:
    return 0
  if a is None:
    return -1
  if b is None:
    return 1
  return cmp(a, b)

results = sorted(results, cmp=nonecmp, ...)
```

This treats `None` as being smaller than all datetime objects.