# Sorting by datetime with possible None values

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort based off a datetime field. There are instances where the field may be null ("None").

This results in an error:

> TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to NoneType

It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178931/in-python-sorting-on-date-field-field-may-sometimes-be-null) would be the ideal way to fix the issue but it does not seem to work for me. Could someone explain what detail I seem to have overlooked? Im OK with Python (not great) and I understand what is supposed to happen here but feel there is some syntax issue I have overlooked.

```
mindate = datetime.date(datetime.MINYEAR,1,1)

def getdepart_date(x):
    return x['depart_date'] or mindate

requests = sorted(unsortedrequests, key=getdepart_date)
```

When I run it, I get the following error on the return line (with double underscores on either side of getitem):

> TypeError: 'StudTransReq' object has no attribute '__getitem_'

Before None datetimes reared their ugly heads the code worked fine as follows:

```
requests = sorted(unsortedrequests, key=attrgetter('depart_date'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've switched from attribute (dot) lookup to dictionary (brackets) lookup, for some reason. Your function should do:

```
return x.depart_date or mindate
```

Note that you can do this as a lambda:

```
requests = sorted(unsortedrequests, key=lambda x: x.depart_date or mindate)
```

Comment: Thanks you, Daniel. That was what I was missing!